# What preposition should I use with "flying"?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say that I loved flying, but I also want to add the name of the airline company in my sentence.

So, what should I say?

> I loved flying with American Airlines

or

> I loved flying on American Airlines.

I've found on my Googling both "with" and "on", and now I'm even more confused than I was before...

Answer (score 3):

Preposition choice is complicated and not always logical, but in this case, it appears that both can be used. You fly *on* an aircraft, so you fly *on* an airline's aircraft, so (using synecdoche) you fly *on* an airline. Similarly, you fly *with* the airline's crew, etc. Note that you can also say

> I like to fly American Airlines

even though this sentence could also be interpreted as saying that you are doing the flying, or that you are taking American Airlines out for a fly, etc, the context makes it clear what you mean.

My personal preference is to use *on* or to leave the preposition out.

The best evidence I can find to demonstrate this is [this ngram, where I searched for "flying with * airline" and "flying on * airline"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flying+on+*+airline%2Cflying+with+*+airline&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cflying%20on%20*%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bflying%20on%20the%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflying%20on%20an%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cflying%20with%20*%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bflying%20with%20the%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflying%20with%20an%20airline%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cflying%20on%20*%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bflying%20on%20the%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflying%20on%20an%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cflying%20with%20*%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bflying%20with%20the%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflying%20with%20an%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflying%20with%20the%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflying%20with%20an%20airline%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cflying%20on%20*%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bflying%20on%20the%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflying%20on%20an%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cflying%20with%20*%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bflying%20with%20the%20airline%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflying%20with%20an%20airline%3B%2Cc0)
 [image]

Comment: That's a fascinating ngram. I'm left wondering if the blue peak corresponds to an advertising campaign.

Answer (score 2):

"I fly *on* American Airlines" is the most common usage I hear.  It is correct because "American Airlines" is being used as a synecdoche.  The name of the company is being used to refer to an aircraft operated by the company.

Answer (score 1):

In everyday speech I would say 'I like flying American Airlines' (no preposition). 'flying on American Airlines ' or 'with American Airlines' sound more like a tv commercial.

Comment: As I recall, TV commercials used indeed to use such locutions as "fly United."

Answer (score 0):

You don't fly *on* American Airlines. American Airlines itself doesn't fly. It's a company, not an airplane. You fly *with* American Airlines.

(By contrast, when you're talking about the airplane itself, or the flight specifically, different prepositions apply: "I flew in my friend's Cessna", "I was on the 5 p.m. flight", etc.)

Comment: You could equally well say 'You don't fly _with_ American Airlines. American Airlines itself doesn't fly. It's a company, not an airplane. You fly in an airplane of American Airlines.' In fact, accepted prepositional usage is often extremely difficult to justify logically; often, words have been standardly omitted which might justify the choice. Here, 'fly with ...' is certainly idiomatic (and an idiom), but that doesn't mean that 'fly on [an airplane of]' is unacceptable (there are many examples on the internet), or, as user3847 adds, 'fly ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough, to *fly with* is idiomatic use. Nonetheless, from an intuitive, logical point of view, I still think that *flying with AA* is clearer and more correct than *flying on AA*, perhaps only descriptively due to colloquial use.

Comment: But if you can say 'You don't fly _on_ American (etc) Airlines', when people obviously _do_ use that idiom, I can surely say 'You shouldn't be so dogmatic, especially without giving any supporting data'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The issue I tried to raise is that though both uses are idiomatic, one of them (*on*) makes less sense than the other. Therefore, I consider the other (*with*) to be the better phrase to use.

Comment: That doesn't sanction 'You don't fly _on_ AmA', with the obvious implication that this is wrong choice. I've been speaking English for over 60 years, but I still check on usages and words I'm not familiar with before writing anything even half as dogmatic as this. (I've also just checked 4 articles I've got on 'preposition choice' – though this particular issue isn't addressed.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps one does not fly on AA, but apparently one flies on BA: [Q. **I flew *on* British Airways** between the U.S. and the U.K. before October 1, 2010. Will I earn AAdvantage miles for that flight?
 A. No. Flights flown prior to October 1 are not eligible for mileage accrual on British Airways flights between the U.S. and the U.K.](https://www.aa.com/i18n/disclaimers/jba-faqs.jsp)  There are other examples of *flying on* or *flight on* there on that American Airlines webpage.  Well, or with that American Airlines webpage; your choice. :)

Comment: I agree with this answer. You don't fly ON American Airlines. Technically that's literally saying you flew *on* the company. Honestly, it's not that big of a deal... mostly everyone will get your meaning whether you use "on" or "with." If you want to get technical I'd say "with" or just: "I flew American Airlines" by itself. But again, both get the point across just fine.

Comment: @tchrist With all due respect to the good folks at American Airlines, I don't consider the word usage on their *FAQ Pages* to be a source of grammatical authority on this issue.